# Local usage of new keyword

Tags: java, oop, locale, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I didn't expect that `new` doesn't change the instance variables if instance variables are already assigned.

Did I understand correctly?

```
class Foo {
    String name = "Java";
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo foos[] = { new Foo(), new Foo() };
        foos[0].name = "bar";
        for (Foo c : foos) c = new Foo();
        for (Foo c : foos) System.out.println(c.name);
        for (Foo c : foos) c.name = "baz";
        for (Foo c : foos) System.out.println(c.name);
    }
}
```

Output

```
bar
Java
baz
baz
```

In the above example, the `new` works more like casting the object to the same class is already it. What is the practical use for this behavior?

Comment: The `new` operator is just doing its job, which is to create new objects.  I see nothing here which requires explanation.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean here...You've got 3 uses of `new` - which of those is what you're surprised by? And what does this have to do with locales? What do you *expect* the result to be? Are you surprised that `c = new Foo();` doesn't actually change the value in the collection? If so, that's got *nothing* to do with `new`.

Comment: There are four independent variables `c`. There is no reassignment except in the first loop. But this has no effect on the array.

Comment: You're changing `c`, not `Foo[0]` or `Foo[1]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because Java is always **pass-by-value**. Variable `c` doesn't reflect the array element, but its reference value is copied. So at first, `c` points to the value of the array element, but when you reassign `c` using `c = new Foo()`, variable `c` will point to something else. For that reason, the array element itself is unaffected.

1. In this code,

   ```
   for (Foo c : foos)
   ```

   the reference to the array element (for example `foos[0]`) is copied to `c`.
2. But when you assign a new `Foo` instance to `c`, it is not reflected by the array, you simply have assigned something to `c`.

   ```
   c = new Foo();
   ```
3. In the next loop iteration, the next element is reassigned to `c`, leaving the object you created by `c = new Foo()` loosely into memory. It will be garbage collected soon.

*I noticed that you're coming from a C world, which explains the confusion. But in Java, arguments passed to a method or the element reference in a foreach loop are always copied. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/507738) explains further details about this behavior.*